# SWRevealViewController Open second view controller from menu programatically using swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SWRevealViewController in my app. Everything is fine except one thing.

Suppose there are A,B,C 3 items in my SWRevealViewController Menu. I want to open B item programatically using swift.

**UPDATE: CODE**

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let sw = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Reveal") as! SWRevealViewController
        let destinationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VehicleList") as! VehicleList
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: destinationController)
        sw.pushFrontViewController(navigationController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Please add code of what you have tried

Comment: @SylvanDAsh I have added code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can have access to the main screen controller using `frontViewController` property of the `SWRevealViewController` like that:

```
let navigationController = revealViewController().frontViewController as? UINavigationController
navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: false)
```

You can replace the frontViewController using `setFront(_:animated:)` function of `SWRevealViewController` like:

```
revealViewController()?.setFront(viewController, animated: false)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your first 2 line did work for me but with some addition. I am answering in full. Thanks @gcharita

Answer (score 0):

This is complete solution two my question.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let destinationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VehicleList") as! VehicleList
        let navigationController = revealViewController().frontViewController as? UINavigationController
        navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationController, animated: false)
```

Comment: There is no need to instantiate `SWRevealViewController` from the Storyboard in line 2

Comment: You are right. This piece of code left from previous update. Let me update it.